# Can't find .vim folder

Tags: vim

I'm a Ubuntu 11.04, 64bit user. I have installed vim via `apt-get` and I need to install plugins, so after the installation process was done, I looked for `.vim` dicectory in `$HOME`,  but I couldn't find it anywhere. Can anyone please help me figure out where the `vim` directory is?

Answer (score 3):

create it by

```
% mkdir ~/.vim
```

(or any other means).

Comment: I create manually .vim and how do I install the vim plugins, do I manually create the plugin directory and put the files in there?

Comment: yes. or just "unzip" the files in the .vim folder.

Comment: It depends on the plugin. A tarball have to be extracted by hand, a vimball need to be sourced from vim, or you may also use a plugins manager like vim-addon-manager, pathogen, etc.